# Add information to days in a month in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I Want to develop a human resource application using [Fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io) , i want know how to
Popup a nice window by clicking on each day to get some information from user. Form is similar for each day and users have to put their working hours in it . Then by clicking on save all the information must save into server and the color of that day in calender should become green which means users already filed this day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [dayClick](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/) method to detect clicking on a day and change color.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
        //create window here
        alert('create window');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks , but before changing the colors in dayClick how can i popup a windows or fancybox ?

Comment: I think you could have figured that out but I improved the answer

Comment: sure ... can you help me one more time ? instead of nice and fancy window how can i open a dialog by clicking on each day ?

Comment: A "dialog" isn't something built into javascript. You need a plugin or something, [here's 17 to choose from](http://www.sitepoint.com/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/)

Comment: I already did put dialog into my page but the problem is i don't know how to open it by clicking on day click function . i use to work with dialog and its simple but in this condition i don't know how to do it ...